# Can I use a sheet of plywood to get a tighter hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor

someone told me that I should screw a sheet of plywood like 8" x 8` long about 10 boards away from my wall and make that my straight edge then start my hardwood from that then after I reached the end go back and take out the plywood and finish it off, he says it will make it a tighter floor then starting close to the wall and nailing the first boards threw the surface? what are your thoughts?

Comment: ...What? I don't understand what this means. Just follow the directions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the way it was suggested, starting with the ripped plywood, yes, will need a spline to change the direction of the floor to fill in the space that was occupied by the plywood, and you will still need to face nail the last 3 or 4 pieces, since the floor nailer will not fit that tightly to the wall. You will need to rack out the flooring and compress it in place using a lever system to draw it all up tight, before it is nailed tight, again, only with the last 3 or 4 rows. The lever can be a prybar with a block of wood to keep from breaking into the drywall or a tapered 2X something to act as a lever

OR

You can do it the way I seen it always done, and the way I do it myself when laying floor in a room with a simple floor plan.
Some guys don't take the time to mark the floor joists, they figure I guess many nails will hold and I am sure it will. If you mark the joists first at the starting edge. Then chalk a line 3/4" wider than your flooring is onto the subfloor, lining the first row of flooring tongue of the T&G flooring on the chalkline. This should give about a 1/2" space to the drywall or framing, which is required, if you use the tongue of the as the reference. This will get covered by the base and shoe mold. To keep this space though not needed in my opinion, you can set 1/2" thick plywood shims to maintain the space.

Now back at nailing. It is a simple operation once the joists are marked, usually on the wall so the base will cover it or use blue painters tape if perhaps the base is in place. That way when you put the paper down you still have reference marks. Next take your longest, straightest strips and set them on the chalk line as mentioned before, set them on the line and shoot 2 nails at each joist location, 1/2" to 3/4" in from each edge of the flooring. Do not worry how the ends of the flooring happen at the joist. You can add a 3rd nail in the tongue, like the flooring nailer that you will eventually use will do. Move on to the next row. This will be nailed once on the face and once in the tongue and do the same for the 3rd row. That should get you to where your nail gun can take over.

Just a mention on the laying of the floor. Maybe you have instructions, maybe you don't. I want to impart some techniques on laying a high quality floor. Just 3 or 4 tips.

1. Keep the ends of your flooring apart from the next row by at least
   6", more the better, but if it needs to be closer than that, so be it.
2. When possible, do not let the breaks (ends) in the flooring line up on subsequent rows no closer than the 3rd row out.
3. Use as much of you can of that short stuff in a closet or pantry if you have one.
4. This one regards layout, check the room for parallel
               walls, tweak it here or there if you need to so a difference will
               not show up on the other side of the room, then it is too late to
               fix. If 2 people are nailing the floor, have them switch sides
               periodically, one person always drives the floor tighter than the
               other. When you get halfway across, measure the room again, you may
               be surprised how the dimension changes. With using more force or
               less on the hammer, you can actually "steer" the floor to finish
               well on the other side, granted, if the difference isn't too drastic.

   Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This is a good idea.

When you nail flooring down, you are putting a fair bit of force against the boards laterally. If you face nail the edge boards, they may slip a little. On the other hand, if you put something solid there (plywood or just solid blocks screwed to the joists), then you have something very solid that will keep the boards from moving.

If you do this, you will need a spline to go in the board when you switch directions. You can get these where you buy the flooring.